# Get a CVS log/history similar to the "git log" command?

Tags: git, cvs

I'm a git guy, but now I have to use CVS in a project temporarily. I haven't been able to find a command that displays a nicely formatted chronological commit list with author, commit message, date and revision (and nothing else).

Instead I get all sorts of useless information about RCS file, locks, etc, and `cvs log` seems to group commits by file rather than by date which makes it hard to get an overview of what has happened in a repository.

Is there a way to do that, dear CVS experts?

Comment: Doesn't CVS support this kind of chronological log at all? I'm also a big fan of Git (in fact, *hated* complicated VC systems like CVS and SVN before I discovered Git and *loved it*) so I'm looking for `git log` style logs in CVS (I cannot convert the repo to Git, so the accepted answer is unhelpful)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `git cvsimport` to import the entire repository into git and then interact with git.  It's not quite as smooth as `git svn`, but it does work well.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a script to display the history of CVS commits similar to Git or SVN:

https://alvinabad.wordpress.com/2015/03/01/display-the-history-of-cvs-commits-similar-to-git-or-svn/

https://github.com/alvinabad/cvs-utils/blob/master/cvs-history.py