# git cvsimport from remote machine accessible via SSPI only?

Tags: windows, git, cvs, sspi

I have a CVS repository on a remote Windows machine, checked out to my local Windows machine. I want to use `git cvsimport` [to have git log](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5815170), but the remote repo is only accessible via SSPI, which, if I understand [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35077886/7050476) correctly doesn't work with git. Is there any way I could use `git cvsimport` in this case? I don't know much about CVS, Windows or SSPI. Could I get the "cvs root" (currently only accessible via SSPI on a remote machine) to my local machine and then do `git cvsimport` to that local path?

This is what I get when trying to access the remote machine (after [some](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18901040/7050476) [fixes](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/12636)):

```
$ git cvsimport -v -d :ext:USER@SERVER:/PATH -r cvs -k MODULE
ssh: connect to host SERVER port 22: Connection timed out
Failed to read from server at C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\mingw32/libexec/git-core\git-cvsimport line 420.
```

As I understand it git is trying to use ssh but the machine only accepts SSPI. I tried using my local checkedout CVS repo instead, to no avail:

```
git cvsimport -v -d :local:`pwd` -r cvs -k MODULE -C/c/OUTDIR
Expected Valid-requests from server, but got: E cvs [server aborted]: PATH: no such repository
```

I have installed the latest version from the git website, accessible through "git bash".

Answer (score 0):

Git doesn't work with SSPI, but you're not asking it to. You're asking cvs to work with SSPI. So the following may still work.

(Assuming your original command is otherwise correct...) You will have to do something like this:
`git cvsimport -v -d :sspi:USER@SERVER:/PATH -r cvs -k MODULE`

Comment: With that command I get that `:sspi:USER@SERVER/PATH` must be an absolute pathname, which is similar to what the user from the question I linked was getting. And according to [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cvsimport) `only the :local:, :ext: and :pserver: access methods are supported`, so...Not possible?

Comment: Ah, sorry. My guess is not possible, but I'm not an expert on this in any way.